# Calculate how many hours until 8 AM

Tags: c#, datetime

I know how to calculate the difference between two dates, but how do I calculate the time between a given date and the next 8 AM?

Comment: Did you try subracting two DateTimes and using the TimeSpan class?

Comment: So if "now" is 1 AM, do you want `31` hours as your result?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var tomorrow8am = now.AddDays(1).Date.AddHours(8);
double totalHours = ( tomorrow8am - now).TotalHours;
```

Comment: Don't call `DateTime.Now` twice, there's a small risk of the first call being right before midnight, and the second right after.  Instead, save `DateTime.Now` in a variable and use that in both calculations.

Answer (score 2):

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
double diffHours = 24 - (now - now.Date).TotalHours + 8;
```

Comment: Could also be written `24.0 - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalHours + 8.0` or `32.0 - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalHours`.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```
var now = DateTime.Now();
var target = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddHours(8);
var result = (target - now).Hour;
```

Answer (score 0):

Works well before 8am the same day.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime next8am =now.Date.AddHours(8);
if(now.TimeOfDay>TimeSpan.FromHours(8))
    next8am.AddDays(1);
return next8am.Subtract(now).TotalHours
```

Comment: This answers the OP's question, which is "the next 8 AM?" 

e.g. if it is now 7 AM, it is 1 hour until 8 AM. The other answers would determine that it is 25 hours until 8 AM, as they blindly add a whole day to the current time.

If you are looking for a way to find how many hours until the very next occurrence of a time, this is the answer for you.

Except for one tiny issue. `AddDays` does not mutate the value upon which it is invoked. You'll need to use the return value. i.e. by assigning it `next8am = next8am.AddDays(1);`