# Easily calculate the time before midnight in C#

Tags: c#, time

I have a function which is already compact, i wanted to know if there was better (like a DateTime functionality already included).

Currently i use this:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
DateTime tomorrow = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, 0, 0, 0).AddDays(1);
double remaining = (tomorrow - today).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Thank for reading.

Comment: You can use short version `var remaining = (DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1) - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate how many hours until 8 AM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785556/calculate-how-many-hours-until-8-am)

Comment: Just use the suggested duplicate without the `.AddHours(8);`. and take what you need from the difference.

Comment: @JeremyCaney There's a specific problem mentioned here, I don't see why this couldn't stay on SO.

Comment: @Mast: Largely because it’s opinion based, asking for a “better” approach.

Comment: @JeremyCaney If I read the answers, some of them are objectively better.

Comment: @Mast: Yes, personally I wish there were more room for “best practice” type questions on Stack Overflow, as often there are established, accepted, defensible understandings of “better” within our field that get shut down here. But, when that happens, Code Review Stack Exchange—and, occasionally, Software Engineering Stack Exchange—is often a good alternative, so I like to make sure contributors are aware of it.

Comment: @JeremyCaney In computer school we were told that it was the best forum for all questions.

And even if we didn't use it, to still say that we use it to be better seen by recruiters.

Anyway for my first question I did not have an "RTFM" :D

I learned a lot, I had never looked at the functionality of "today" or "and" and i had no idea that you could make an extension, very useful to use in multiple threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create extension for `DateTime`

```
public static class DateExtensions
{
   public static double GetNextDayRemainingMs(this DateTime dateTime)
   {
      return (dateTime.AddDays(1).Date - dateTime).TotalMilliseconds;
   }
}
```

Usage

```
DateTime.Now.GetNextDayRemainingMs();
```

Comment: A feature that I did not know! Thank you for making me discover this ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify the tomorrow value by just doing this and taking the benefit of `DateTime.Today`:

```
DateTime tomorrow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
```

So your code will be easy to read:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
DateTime tomorrow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
double remaining = (tomorrow - today).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining instance for `tomorrow` variable you can use `.AddDate(1).Date` property

> `.AddDate(1)` will add one day to `DateTime.Now` and `.Date` property
> will give you only date and sets time to `00`.

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now; 
double remaining = (today.AddDate(1).Date - today).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Or *(Elegant way)*

You can use [`Today`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.today?view=net-5.0) property of `DateTime`.

> An object that is set to today's date, with the time component set to
> 00:00:00.

```
double remaining = (DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)-DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, you taught me a lot!
With such basic features, we learn so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code

```
(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)-DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds
```

Comment: Yes it's work, i did not know "today", thank you ! (even if several of you have told me, but thank you anyway!)